# How do I move a spill array across multiple columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to move spill array output across multiple columns with a divider between each column?  I am using the filter function to group individuals with certain attributes together on a separate sheet with four columns.  Column A has 50 entries, B has 50, etc.  Is there a way to filter the results to end at row 50 in column A and then begin at row 1 in Column B?

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome! Just select all numbers in first column (1, 2, 3 etc.) and press [**Ctrl+Shift+Plus sign (+)**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f#bkmk_freqwin) - it will open the Insert dialog box to insert blank cells. Choose shift to right

Comment: I get what you're going for there, however I want the data to spill over to column 2 after filling column 1.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking

Comment: If it is just one column then `Wrapcols` works, otherwise, please edit your post to clarify your ask.

Comment: Breaks line? 0 0